# Data Tables Jquery Dynamic Fill

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables in one of my projects in which I have to fill it with the Oracle query results. I am referring to [this document](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html).

**Problem:**

All the 10 columns returned by query get displayed in row 1 column 1 of the table.

**Javascript**

```
$('#inquiryForm').submit(function(){    
    var cnic = "data="+ $( "#cnicInd" ).val();
    //alert(cnic);

     $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/inquiryInd.php",
    data: cnic,
    success: function(datapage) {
          //$("#errmsg").html(data).show();
          var datacopy = [[datapage]]; 

    prompt("Result",datacopy);
     $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({   
            responsive: true,
            "data": datacopy,
             columns: [
        { title: "Policy No." },
        { title: "Client Name" },
        { title: "Gross Premium" },
        { title: "Next Due Date" },
        { title: "Commencement Date" },
        { title: "Cash Value" },
        { title: "Total Amount Paid" },
        { title: "Total Amount Due" },
        { title: "Total unconsumed Amount" },
        { title: "Status" }
    ]

    });

    }
   });

     $('#searchTable').show();
        return false;               
    });
```

**inquiryInd.php**

```
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stmnt)) != false) {

$result = "";

$result .= '"'.$row['PROPOSAL']."\"";
$result .= ',"'.$row['FULLNAME']."\"";
$result .= ',"'.$row['GROSSPREMIUM']."\"";
$result .= ',"'.$row['NEXTDUEDAT']."\"";
$result .= ',"'.$row['COMMENDATE']."\"";
$result .= ',"'.$row['CASH_VALUE']."\"";
$result .= ',"'.$row['TOTAL_AMOUNT_PAID']."\"";
$result .= ',"'.$row['TOTAL_AMOUNT_DUE']."\"";
$result .= ',"'.$row['TOTAL_AMOUNT_DUE']."\"";
$result .= ',"'.$row['STATUS']."\"";
//$result .= ']';
$dataset .= $result;

//Something like  "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" 
}
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Use `json_encode`over `php` end and `JSON.parse` over client-side!

Comment: @RayonDabre is there any other alternative? I don't have JSON installed on server side.

Comment: First, @RayonDabre is right and there is no need to install JSON on server side php & js come with those functions you should read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php).
anyway.. no matter how you choose to pass your data you have to parse it for datatabels. The "data" property for DataTables needs a 2D array of strings where each array represents a row in the tables. For a table with 3 columns it'll look something like this:
[
["someString", "anotherOne", "and this is also goo"],
["abc", "more", "col3"]
]